# OpenCL doesn't detect GPU

Tags: c++, opencl, ubuntu-14.04, gpu

I installed AMD APP SDK and here my problem. The OpenCL samples do not detect the GPU. HelloWorld give me this:

```
[thomas@Clemence:/opt/AMDAPP/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64]$ ./HelloWorld
No GPU device available.
Choose CPU as default device.
input string:
GdkknVnqkc

output string:
HelloWorld
Passed!
```

And here the clinfo output

```
[thomas@Clemence:~/Documents/radeontop]$ clinfo
Number of platforms:                 1
Platform Profile:                FULL_PROFILE
Platform Version:                OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform Vendor:                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform Extensions:                 cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback  cl_amd_offline_devices


Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               1
Device Type:                     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
Device ID:                   4098
Board name:                  
Max compute units:               8
Max work items dimensions:           3
Max work items[0]:               1024
Max work items[1]:               1024
Max work items[2]:               1024
Max work group size:                 1024
Preferred vector width char:             16
Preferred vector width short:            8
Preferred vector width int:          4
Preferred vector width long:             2
Preferred vector width float:            8
Preferred vector width double:       4
Native vector width char:            16
Native vector width short:           8
Native vector width int:             4
Native vector width long:            2
Native vector width float:           8
Native vector width double:          4
Max clock frequency:                 3633Mhz
Address bits:                    64
Max memory allocation:           4182872064
Image support:               Yes
Max number of images read arguments:         128
Max number of images write arguments:        8
Max image 2D width:              8192
Max image 2D height:                 8192
Max image 3D width:              2048
Max image 3D height:                 2048
Max image 3D depth:              2048
Max samplers within kernel:          16
Max size of kernel argument:             4096
Alignment (bits) of base address:        1024
Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:  128
Single precision floating point capability
Denorms:                     Yes
Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
Round to nearest even:           Yes
Round to zero:               Yes
Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
Cache type:                  Read/Write
Cache line size:                 64
Cache size:                  32768
Global memory size:              16731488256
Constant buffer size:                65536
Max number of constant args:             8
Local memory type:               Global
Local memory size:               32768
Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:   1
Error correction support:            0
Unified memory for Host and Device:      1
Profiling timer resolution:          1
Device endianess:                Little
Available:                   Yes
Compiler available:              Yes
Execution capabilities:              
Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
Execute native function:             Yes
Queue properties:                
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  Yes
Platform ID:                     0x00007f4ef63f0fc0
Name:                        Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Vendor:                  GenuineIntel
Device OpenCL C version:             OpenCL C 1.2 
Driver version:              1214.3 (sse2,avx)
Profile:                     FULL_PROFILE
Version:                     OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
Extensions:                  cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt
```

What should I do in order to have access to the GPU? Thanks in advance.
I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Trusty Kernel 3.9

here my graphics card:

```
[thomas@elsa:~]$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th 
Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350]
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ./HelloWorld`? Have you tried stopping lightdm `sudo service lightdm stop`?

Comment: Nope, nothing has worked. Do you have another ideas?

Comment: Is `dmesg | grep fglrx | grep module` returning something?

Answer (score 0):

Not all GPU´s in the market support OpenCL.
You already check it out if your GPU support OpenCL?
Your GPU Drivers are up to date?

When this heppen to me , the root cause was i change the graphics card, but without update the driver , the deafult windows driver are used.